# How to check whether a file exists inside of a "foreach" in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, foreach, gnu-make

So I have a variable with file names, however I am not sure whether these file names exist. I want to put the ones that exist into some other variable.
All this is happening in a Makefile.

Here is one of my many tries to accomplish it:

FILES is the preset variable containing the set of the files.

```
OUTPUT += $(foreach file, $(FILES), \
                   ifneq (,$(wildcard $(file))
                     $(file)
                   endif
```

Obviously it doesn't work for many reasons, just trying to make clear what I want to achieve.

Also I would like to avoid using $(shell *) if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `wildcard` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html#Wildcard-Function) takes *multiple* targets, and unlike shell globs *non-matching patterns are omitted* from the output, so I would expect this to work:

```
OUTPUT = $(wildcard $(FILES))
```

Comment: You really want to use `:=` here, if at all possible.  It's a major performance boost.

Comment: "Major?" I smell premature optimisation.